# Can't disabled 'compiled_config' cache

Tags: magento2.3, cache

Updating a project from 2.1.x to 2.3.  Running into an weird issue where 'compiled_config' cache won't disable.  Tried disabling via cli with

```
php bin/magento cache:disable compiled_config
```

and it will output

```
Changed cache status:
     compiled_config: 1 -> 0
```

But the cache will turn right back on.

Also tried to disable through env.php and it will turn right back on as well.

Not seeing anything related in Magento logs.  All other caches will disable.

Anyone know where to look or how to resolve this?

Comment: Seems it bug at magento 2.3version.I have posted the issue at Github repo https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23133

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Amit.